# Orthogonality as found by the Gram-Schmidt process vs. uncorrelated basis vectors

Tags: pca, independence, svd, eigenvalues

I have a data matrix $Y$ of size $n \times p$, a basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^p$ $v_1$, and a potential basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^p$ $v_2'$. Then, if I use the Gram-Schmidt process on $[v_1, v_2']$ to produce $v_2$ orthogonal to $v_1$, it is not necessarily true that for $B = [v_1, v_2]$, the transformed data matrix $YB$ of size $n \times 2$ consists of two uncorrelated variables.

Can the Gram-Schmidt process be modified to produce *uncorrelated* basis vectors, analogous to PCA? Mathematically, I'm having trouble visualizing the difference between orthogonal according to the Euclidean dot product and uncorrelated statistically. PCA obviously finds both, but that's unique as it corresponds to the eigendecomposition which is mathematically "special" as well, but in what way?

Comment: For the concept of "correlation" to apply you need to posit some kind of multivariate distribution.  That's not always the case for an arbitrary "data matrix."  Please, then, tell us what distribution you might be assuming for these data.

Comment: Sorry, we can assume that $Y$ follows some arbitrary multivariate normal distribution with at least some non-zero off-diagonal covariances. Is this specific enough?

Comment: No, because it doesn't clarify your question.  If you want "uncorrelated" vectors you need to explain the sense in which we are to understand and compute correlation.  The problem here is that Euclidean orthogonality of vectors in this context has nothing at all to do with correlation of random variables, leaving your readers wondering what you're trying to accomplish and what you're attempting to ask.

Comment: I see. So it's not the distribution of the data, but the definition of correlation. In that case, Pearson correlation.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the relationship between orthogonality in Euclidean space and statistical independence, either intuitively or mathematically. For example, is it a necessary condition for the basis to be orthogonal in Euclidean space? It is clearly not sufficient, so what else is needed?

Comment: *There is no direct relationship.*  The one you might be thinking of is that in a space of *random variables* (which often is infinite dimensional) one can define a norm and inner product and use Euclidean concepts to interpret lack of correlation geometrically. The orthogonality calculations you describe are not relevant to any concept of independence generally.  They do have some bearing in the situation where you assume the data columns are realizations of a multivariate Normal (Gaussian) variable.

Comment: `Can the Gram-Schmidt process be modified to produce uncorrelated basis vectors, analogous to PCA?` No. In PCA, X=PV' where X is the data, V is orhonormal matrix of eigenvectors, P is pr. component scores, uncorrelated, so that P'P=diagonal matrix. In GS, X=RQ', where R is orthonormal basis, R is triangular (and so R'R cannot be diagonal). In PCA, the first principal dimension (of V and P) has the direction of the maximal _sum-of-squares_ of the data (or of variance, if X is centered), the 2nd dim. is perpendicular to it and is second max. SS, and so on.

Comment: (cont.) In GS, the first dimension is the direction pointing at the _first data point_, the 2nd dim. is perpendicular to it and forms the plain (with the 1st dim.) containing the second data point, and so on. The directions are thus predermined by individual data points of X and their order.

Comment: @whuber thank you. That clarifies things for me considerably.

Comment: @ttnphns Obviously the eigendecomposition is unique, but does that mean for every data matrix $Y$ which satisfies the constraints mentioned in the above discussion there is a unique basis (i.e. that found by eigendecomposition) where the data is uncorrelated? (Or is it up to sign switches?)

Comment: If by "uncorrelated" you mean "orthogonal," the answer is "generically yes, up to arbitrary nonzero multiples of the basis elements."  The exceptions occur when the multiplicity of an eigenvalue is greater than $1.$ The most extreme--yet illustrative--example concerns a data matrix of zeros, for which *all* bases of $\mathbb{R}^p$ are eigenbases.

Answer (score 3):

Check the following two papers, where Modified Gram Schmidt technique plays a central role for a new technique called Reduced Basis Decomposition. 
As per the author it can't achieve a better accuracy than Principal Component Analysis. However the second paper given below shows a strong empirical evidence that by selecting the correct error estimation norm, we can obtain superior results than PCA.

1. [Reduced Basis Decomposition - Original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05947)
2. [Recently Published Paper with empirical evidence and a new error estimation norm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11554-018-0778-8)